# Google chrome screen content freezes

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, freeze

We have an old web application (`javascript jquery + css`) that it is displayed in a lot of displays (`google chrome browser`), randomly (we do not know the casuistry) the browser active tab content freezes. We can open a new browser window and it woks normally.

The `javascript` does changes to the `DOM` and we can see them in developer console, but the content does not change.
We also tried to override the `DOM` through the browser console with same effect.
We tried to do a `location.reload()` and we saw in the console that browser downloads all (`javascript, css files` etc..) but the screen continues unaltered.

The software version we are using:

`Browser: Google chrome 44` (same version in another installations and we never experimented this issue before)
`OS: Linux Centos 7.2`
`Graphin card Drivers: Nvidia different versions`.

Different configurations tried (not solving the problem):
- `GPU enabled`
- `GPU disabled`

Currently we are trying this actions to see if solves the issue (we do not have results yet )
- Update `Google Chrome` to latest version 
- Update Nidivia drivers` to latest version

Any idea about why is this happening?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks you all very much.

Comment: Chrome 44 is 5 years old.

Comment: You probably have poor JavaScript that's blocking the UI, such as synchronous AJAX or long loops. You need to learn to write asynchronous and event-driven code. But I'm just guessing, since you haven't posted any code that we can review.